# Why extended permissions are lost from second facebook login onwards using facebook graph api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on Asp.Net MVC. I am trying to integrate Facebook with my web application using Facebook Graph API. I am using OAuth mechanism to pull data from facebook. At first step i have called the endpoint like,

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,read_friendlists");
```

That means, User was redirected to facebook login page and he enters his credentials and after the confirmation of valid credentials it asks for permissions like `public profile Info, email,etc.` in first dialog. In second dialog, it asks for `post on your wall behalf of you` if the user select ok for all permissions he gets redirected back to redirect uri with authroization code. and i get access token using this endpoint like,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={appid}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={appsecret}&code={authorization code}
```

and also i extended this short-lived access token like

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={appid}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={appsecret}&fb_exchange_token={accesstoken above}
```

and i got the access token and save it into my database.

And i just inspect the permission of the user that he selects just before using Graph API Explorer and i got the response like,

```
"installed": 1, 
"basic_info": 1, 
"email": 1, 
"user_likes": 1, 
"user_photos": 1, 
"user_notes": 1, 
"user_subscriptions": 1,
"publish_stream":1,
"read_stream":1,
"read_friendlists":1
```

ok everything works fine upto now. Now i logged out from facebook site and decided to login freshly through my app. after login into facebook and it does not allow me to redirect to my site it always stuck into that facebook login page and i observe the address bar url at the end of it says user denied and error code 200. and i check the permissions for the user using graph api explorer and i got response like,

```
"installed": 1, 
"basic_info": 1, 
"email": 1, 
"user_likes": 1, 
"user_photos": 1, 
"user_notes": 1, 
"user_subscriptions": 1
```

here i observe that i lost the extended permissions `publish_stream,read_stream` thats why it does not allow me to my site. But if already logged in facebook site and access my site i am able to access user profile, timeline etc. without getting any error. and also if i add `auth_type=reauthenticate` along with scope it succeeds me however it asks user for login about 2 times that is not my requirement. Why extended permissions are lost from second time login. Please guide me if i went wrong in my process. Thank you.

Comment: It could be the way you're logging the user out of your application. How are you currently doing it?

Comment: I am just logging out the user from my application only not facebook. I am just clearing out session. I am not using like FB.Logout etc.